# How can I mock Kafka AdminClient to return topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, mockito

How can I mock Kafka AdminClient to return certain topic?
I want to test this method in unit tests, but have problems with mocking AdminClient which underneath all the time tries to connect to the real cluster of Kafka...
I cannot use PowerMockito because of Junit5, only normal Mockito library.

Here is my method, Thank you for your help, but I am a beginner in Mockito

```
public List<String> getTopicByAddresses(String brokerAddresses) throws TopicsNameNotFound {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerAddresses);
    try (AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(props)) {
        ListTopicsOptions listTopicsOptions = new ListTopicsOptions();
        listTopicsOptions.timeoutMs(5000);
        result = adminClient.listTopics(listTopicsOptions).names().get()
                .stream().filter(StringUtils::hasLength).toList();

    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new TopicsNameNotFound("Topics name not found for connection name: " + brokerAddresses);
    }
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        throw new TopicsNameNotFound("Topics name not found for connection name: " + brokerAddresses);
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: try injecting admin client as object then it's easy to mock `listTopics`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, change your parameter to use a pre-configured/mocked client rather than the bootstrap servers.

You can extract the client creation to its own method, too, if you want to test that in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the thing I was stuck with. Basically here you have to use `spy` .

The difference is that in mock, you are creating a complete mock or fake object while in spy, there is the real object and you just spying or stubbing specific methods of it.

Move this part `AdminClient.create(props)` to a new method

```
public List<String> getTopicByAddresses(String brokerAddresses) throws TopicsNameNotFound {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerAddresses);
    try (AdminClient adminClient = createAdminClient(props)) { //***CHANGED LINE***
        ListTopicsOptions listTopicsOptions = new ListTopicsOptions();
        listTopicsOptions.timeoutMs(5000);
        result = adminClient.listTopics(listTopicsOptions).names().get()
                .stream().filter(StringUtils::hasLength).toList();

    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new TopicsNameNotFound("Topics name not found for connection name: " + brokerAddresses);
    }
    if (result.isEmpty()) {
        throw new TopicsNameNotFound("Topics name not found for connection name: " + brokerAddresses);
    }
    return result;

}
public AdminClient createAdminClient() {
        return AdminClient.create(props));
    }
```

let's consider this method is under a class named `TopicByAddress`
Then In your test class -

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TopicByAddressTest {

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private TopicByAddress topicByAddress;

    @Test
    public void topicByAddressTestMethod() {

        AdminClient adminClient = mock(AdminClient.class);
       doReturn(adminClient).when(topicByAddress).createAdminClient();//This is where you are mocking the call and creating a mock object of AdminClient

        /*
          Further you can create mocks of each return types in the method 
        chains
        */
        ListTopicsResult topicRes = mock(ListTopicsResult.class);
        KafkaFuture<Set<String>> kafFuture = mock(KafkaFutureImpl.class);
        when(adminClient.listTopics()).thenReturn(topicRes);
        when(topicRes.names()).thenReturn(kafFuture);
        when(kafFuture.get()).thenReturn(getKafkaTopicNames());
when(adminClient.listTopics().names().get()).thenReturn(getKafkaTopicNames());

        topicByAddress.getTopicByAddresses();
    }

    private Set<String> getKafkaTopicNames() {
        return Set.of("topic1", "topic2");
    }
}
```